# Pandas: Faster way to iterate through a dataframe and add new data based on operations

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pandas to look into values in 2 columns in each row of df1, look for the match in another df2, and paste this in a new column in df1 in the same row and continue

```
alp=list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSUVQXYZ")
df1['NewCol'] = (np.random.choice(alp)) #create new col and input random values

for i in range(len(df1['code1'])):
    a = df1['code2'].iloc[i].upper()
    b = df1['code1'].str[-3:].iloc[i]
    df1['NewCol'].iloc[i] = df2.loc[b,a]
df1['code3'] = df1[['code3','NewCol']].max(axis=1)
df1 =df1.drop('NewCol',axis=1)
```

My inputs as below:
df1:

```
    code1 code2  code3
0  XXXHYG     a     12
1  XXXTBG     a     23
2  XXXECT     b     34
3  XXXKOL     b     45
4  XXXBTW     c     56
```

df2:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
HYG 33  38  40  41  30
TBG 20  46  41  43  45
ECT 53  42  39  34  45
KOL 45  51  54  47  30
BTW 37  36  49  48  58
```

output needed:

```
    code1 code2  code3
0  XXXHYG     a     33
1  XXXTBG     a     23
2  XXXECT     b     42
3  XXXKOL     b     51
4  XXXBTW     c     56
```

When I do this over just 4200 rows in df1, it takes 222 seconds for just the loop.. there has got to be a way to utilize the power of pandas to do this faster?

thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `apply` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)), but a faster way to do this if you have a lot of data would be to create a version of `df2` with a `MultiIndex` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html)) using `stack` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)) and look up values on this new DataFrame.

```
df3 = df1.copy()
tups = list(zip(df1['code1'].str[-3:], df1['code2'].str.upper()))
df3['code3'] = df2.stack()[tups].values
print(df3)
```

outputs

```
    code1 code2  code3
0  XXXHYG     a     33
1  XXXTBG     a     20
2  XXXECT     b     42
3  XXXKOL     b     51
4  XXXBTW     c     49
```

Comment: apologies, I ticked it done as I just checked on the time taken for the above and it was super quick as expected.

however, when I check the output, it is all NaNs .. let me confirm if am doing anything wrong here and come back to tick done pls. Thanks a lot again for you time!

Comment: thanks again, I guess one change to be made in your 2nd line:

`tups = list(zip(df1['code2'].str.upper(),df1['code1'].str[-3:]))`

as df2.stack() comes in that order.. but this is fantastic (as I would have expected out of pandas)! thanks once again..

Comment: @spiff hmm that would be if the `code2` was level 0 of the MultiIndex. `df2.stack()` with the `df2` you posted has `code` as level 0 of the MultiIndex.

Comment: aah.. apologies again. with you now.. thanks vm! 
another interesting thing I found.. the numbers in your method are exactly same as df2, however in my method for some reason they were rounding off after number of decimals as displayed in my df2!